# multi part identifier sql inner join

Tags: sql-server, join

I am creating an inner join between my tables `companydetails` and`zonerpm`.

I wrote this query:

```
select distinct 
    coma.comname 
from 
    companydetails 
inner join
    zonerpm zona  on coma.id = zona.comname
where 
    zona.trainer = 'ayan pal'
```

but I get these errors:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "coma.id" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'comname'.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The  multi-part identifier "coma.comname" could not be bound.

Comment: you might just need '..from companydetails AS coma  ....' at the moment, coma doesn't seem to mean anything

Comment: @AndrewDeighton sir thank u :)

Comment: why the downvote on the question?  The question gives full details

Comment: @AndrewDeighton even i dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an alias on companydetails

```
 select distinct coma.comname from companydetails coma 
 inner join
 zonerpm zona  on coma.id=zona.comname
 where zona.trainer='ayan pal'
```